# Registering for GCM from Server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to register an Android device for GCM via a http call say from server instead of from within the Android app? Assuming I have the device-token and app id.
Python code samples / links to python code would be superb!

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to get a registration id from the GCMRegistrar class. That is based on the device and the app installation. In theory you might be able to dig through the source code of the GCMRegistrar (if you have it) and you might be able to figure out a way to generate the id on your own, but I doubt it.